# how to display list page in blazor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working with codefirst approach in blazor and mydatabase created successfully using code first approach

**fist I create a project and then select a visual studio 2019 -> blazor app -> blazor server app**

why my employee list page not render in blazor

I want to display emp table record in blazor but issue is not render

Emp.cs

```
namespace BlazorServerApp.Pages
{
    public class Emp
    {
        public int empid { get; set; }
        public string empname { get; set; }
        public string empcountry { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EmployeAccessLayer.css

```
namespace BlazorServerApp.DataAccess
{
    public interface IEmployeAccessLayer
    {
        IEnumerable GetAllEmployees();
    }

    public class EmployeAccessLayer : IEmployeAccessLayer
    {
        private MyDbContext _context;
        public EmployeAccessLayer(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable GetAllEmployees()
        {
            try
            {
                return _context.emps.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EmployeeController.css

```
namespace BlazorServerApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
    {
        IEmployeAccessLayer _employeAccessLayer;

        public EmployeeController(IEmployeAccessLayer employeAccessLayer)
        {
            _employeAccessLayer = employeAccessLayer;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Employee/Index")]
        public IEnumerable<Emp> Index()
        {
            return (IEnumerable<Emp>)_employeAccessLayer.GetAllEmployees();
        }
    }
}
```

GetEmployee.razor

```
@*@page "/employee/GetEmployee"*@
@*@page  "/employee"*@
@page  "/employee/"
@inject HttpClient Http

<h3>GetEmployee</h3>

@code {

}
@if (empList == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>EmpID</th>
                <th>EmpName</th>
                <th>EmpCountry</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var emp in empList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@emp.empid</td>
                    <td>@emp.empname</td>
                    <td>@emp.empcountry</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    Emp[] empList;
}
```

NavMenu.razor

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**see my database image
I have 2 record in table I want to display them in blazor**

[image]

**see my blazor output**

[image]

hierarchy of myproject

[image]

here give an message sorry at this nothing address

**Edit:
I add this line in GetEmployee.razor**

```
@code {
    Emp[] empList;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() =>
        empList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Emp[]>("api/Employee/Index");
}
```

but when I am run the project and write this line in address bar then give below error

[image]

**Startup.cs**

```
namespace BlazorServerApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlserverconn")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see where, in your page, you actually call the controller's methods to retrieve the list to put something into `empList`.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti actually call the controller's methods to retrieve the list to put something into empList  yes I want to display that data on home page

Comment: Why do you want to provide a rest-api with you blazor server app?
You can directly query the database with the injected DbContext in you code section.

Comment: @PinBack can you give referance for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to provide a rest-api  with you blazor server app?
You can directly query the database with the injected DbContext in you code section.

You add the dbcontext to the service collection (ConfigureServices).
Now you can use these context in your code section:

```
@page  "/employee/"
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
@inject MyDbContext Context

<h3>GetEmployee</h3>

@if (empList == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>EmpID</th>
                <th>EmpName</th>
                <th>EmpCountry</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var emp in empList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@emp.empid</td>
                    <td>@emp.empname</td>
                    <td>@emp.empcountry</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}


@code {

    private List<Emp> empList;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.empList = await Context.emps.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: see this image I am facing with this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWo3e.png ```Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'SqlServerContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) BlazorServerApp C:\Users\FrontTech\source\repos\BlazorApp\BlazorServerApp\Pages\GetEmployee.razor 1 Active```

Comment: See Update SqlServerContext -> MyDbContext

Comment: I don't understood without using http request data are get?

Comment: I think use http when working with webassembly app to send the request?

Comment: You use Blazor server-side. This has nothing to do with WebAssembly.
This kind of application communication with the server via WebSockets (SignalR).
There a lot of resources where the difference between Server Side and WASM is explained.

Comment: ok I want to call this method ```Index()``` in clientside(webassembly is this possible?

Comment: Then you have to create a Blazor WebAssemlby App.
Here you can't use directly the DbContext. 
Your code execute on the client and here you absolutely need a WebApi.
There is a big different between Blazor Server App and Blazor WebAssemlby App.

Comment: I am calling api in Blazor WebAssemlby but give an error https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7PBK.png   and this is my webapi output but I am trying to call this webapi in webassembly but give an error can you help more please https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYaiU.png

Comment: There are a lot of examples, e.g. https://morioh.com/p/95fc157e4da1
Read and understand what happens in a Blazor WebAssemlby app

Answer (score 0):

you forget call to your API see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() => 
        empList= await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp[]>("api/Employee/Index");
```

Futhermore, remember the direction of your page must be `localhost:44326/employee`

Comment: here give an error https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfCTh.png

Comment: check the docs, posible you forget include  `@using System.Net.Http` or else more

Comment: I add this not solved error ```@using System.Net.Http```

Comment: error is gone after install this  ```Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient -Version 3.1.0-preview4.19579.2``` but page not render

Comment: when I writing this ```localhost:44326/employee``` then get this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSpC6.png

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is not registered as service in the **Startup.cs** which is the cause i think of this issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSpC6.png.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
  .....
}
```

Comment: after add this above line again give an error https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J0hN.png

Answer (score 0):

In your startup class in the configure service method you should have something along the lines of:

```
 services.AddHttpClient("httpClient",client => 
 {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44326/");
 });
```

or if you follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```
services.AddScoped(sp => 
  new HttpClient
  {
   BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44326/")
  });
```

Your controller routing is not correct.

if you have `[Route("api/[controller]")]` on your controller you only need `[Route("Index")]` above your method.

the way you have it in your code the api route is looking for `api/Employee/api/Employee/Index`

change your api code to:

```
namespace BlazorServerApp.Controllers
{
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
  {
   //.....your code here
   // .... your code here
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Index")]
    public IEnumerable<Emp> Index()
    {
       return (IEnumerable<Emp>)_employeAccessLayer.GetAllEmployees();
    }
  }
}
```

I personally prefer using the `GetAsync(...)` like this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{    
    var response = await Http.GetAsync("api/employee/index", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
      empList = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Emp[]>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });      
    }
    else                
      empList = new List<Emp>();
}
```

That way you get a bit more information about why the call to the api failed.

Comment: when I am write your code then give an compile time error see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SH2L.png

Comment: I want to put link in Employee on that page and when I cick on employee then open index page bydefault

Comment: see this image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGHYj.png I change as you said all thing not display the database data on that page

Comment: I think you should spend some time and learn how to use web api and then study blazor. your controller is incorrect. I'll update the code again..

Comment: Start by following this channel on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVowClAs8-6nYnfsOTma14P) or go through the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)